# A Series Fails The Test For Divergence, but is Still Divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I know 
$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n*ln(n)} 
$
is divergent by the integral test or comparison test; however, I notice that it fails the Series Test For Divergence ($\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n \neq 0 \Rightarrow Divergence$). Can a series fail this test and still diverge?

Comment: You answered your question yourself: You gave an example of a divergent series for which the terms being added converge to $0$.

Comment: Yeah, but I just want to know why it's a theorem if it doesn't hold in all situations.

Comment: The theorem says: If $A$ then $B$. It does not say $A$ and $B$ are equivalent.

Comment: (In fact, it is an almost useless test. In most cases of divergent series one actually encounters in practice, the terms being added still converge to $0$.)

Comment: I will buy that. That was pretty much where I was going next. Since this is looking to be the case, the test must be inconclusive in many cases. Thanks.

Comment: I guess the best way to conceptualize this theorem is to say if $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ the test is inconclusive, instead of my previous reasoning: if $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0 \Rightarrow$ Non-divergence.

Comment: Yes, exactly.${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, decay of the summand as $ n \rightarrow \infty$ is a necessary, not sufficient condition for convergence of the series.

Answer (score 1):

a simple example is summation of $\frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 0):

It goes in only one way. If $lim_{n\to \infty} a_n \neq 0$ then the series diverge. It's a minimal criterial, not a sufficient condition